# I want to exception of linux command

Tags: linux, python-2.7, wifi

I want to control on python 
try catch wifi list and connect to catching wife name and password 
but I use linux command so I can't care linux error window
I want to check password in python
when i set wrong password, open Network manager.
What should i do?

```
import commands

def space_filter(x):
    if x == ' ':
        pass
    else:
        return x

#fail, output = commands.getstatusoutput("nmcli dev wifi list")
test= commands.getoutput("nmcli dev wifi list")
test1=test.split(' ')

print test
print test1
test2 = []

test1 = list(filter(space_filter, test1))
#print test1
for x in range(len(test1)):
    if test1[x] == '\n*' or test1[x] =='\n':
        test2.append(test1[x+1])

#print test2
try:
    result = commands.getoutput("nmcli d wifi connect " + test2[0] + " password 1234")
    print result
except:
    print "password is wrong"[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are a language specific construct to catch abnormal/error situations. The correct way to check error conditions in shell commands is the return value.

Use the getstatusoutput function in commands module to catch the return value along with the output. In your case, you would need to parse the output along with the return code to get the reason for failure since nmcli only distinguishes between certain kinds of failure. -  https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html

```
    (status, output) = commands. getstatusoutput("nmcli d wifi connect " + test2[0] + " password 1234")
    if not status:
           print "error"
```

Comment: but I don't want to see  linux os error window "Wi-Fi Network Authentication Required".
It raise when connect wifi and wrong password. 
I want to check before raise linux window. or Hide this

Comment: You may need to disable the GUI frontend to the network manager. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Front-ends

Exact instructions depend on which desktop environment you are using.

Comment: I checked the your comment and site for a day. but I conldn't find disable GUI Option. I use mintos 19. Can you tell me where to look? Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: or if you know python example about connect wifi, please recommand me